# PMA exercise 7.13

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

I don't understand why all of these steps of the hint to prove a). Is monotone convergence theorem enough to prove a? The sequence is bounded and monotone then $\exists N(\epsilon,x)$ s.t $|f_n(x)- f(x)|<\epsilon,\ \forall n\ge N(\epsilon,x)$.

[image]
And why $f_n(x)$ does't converge for all $n$?

Comment: Each function is monotonically increasing. This is not saying for a fixed $x$ that $f_n(x)$ is monotonically increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help to consider a specific example. Let
\begin{equation*}
f_n(x) 
= 
\begin{cases}
0, & x<0\\
x^{n^{(-1)^{n+1}}}, & 0 \leq x < 1\\
1, & 1 \leq x
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
so $f_1(x)=x$, $f_2(x)=x^{1/2}$, $f_3(x)= x^3$, $f_4(x) = x^{1/4}$, etc. on $[0,1]$.

Then each function is monotonically increasing. What can you say about subsequences?